# Boundary of a 3-simplex.

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplex

Label the vertices of the 3-simplex pyramid (1,2,3,4) by $1,2,3,4$. If one follows the brute force formula, we know the boundary equals $234-134+124-123$.

Traversing by the indices in the order $1,2,3,4$ (the default orientation), I am getting $123+234+134+124$.  Rearranging gives me $234 + 134 + 124 + 123$.

I thought by default the simplex $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 4$ goes in that order so why are $123$ and $134$ negative? Note that working backwards will get me the negative on $123$ because of how $341$ is defined.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "I am getting $123+\cdots$"?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown by adding the faces.

Comment: This might be wrong, but if you add the 2-simplices like that you will always get positive coefficients for everything – doesn't the definition of the boundary operator give you a linear combination of the 2-simplices with orientation induced by the orientation on the 3-simplex? What is your definition for boundary operator? In other words, the boundary operator doesn't just give you all the 2-simplices with positive orientation, it does a little more than that.

Comment: @KeshavSutrave well the thing is the definition of the boundary is given after a few examples. But I already wrote it down

Comment: @KeshavSutrave well my problem is that along the $3\to1$ segment, it can be both $+$ and $-$ since it is shared by the common triangle simplex

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you got the idea that you should get $123+234+134+124$.  That's simply not the definition of the boundary.  The definition of the boundary is the alternating sum $234-134+124-123$.  When you write $123+234+134+124$, all you're doing is listing out all of the boundary faces and adding them up.  That's a perfectly good operation to do if you want, but it's not the definition of the boundary.

I think you are perhaps confusing the natural induced ordering on the vertices of each boundary face with the natural orientation on each boundary face as part of the boundary.  Each boundary face has a natural order on its vertices, given by just restricting the order on the vertices of the entire simplex.  Each boundary face also has an orientation which makes it "face outwards" as part of the boundary of the simplex.  However, these two notions are not the same: the order of the vertices in the boundary face need not be compatible with its orientation as a boundary face.  Indeed, for (about) half of the faces this is not true, and those are exactly the faces which receive a minus sign in the boundary formula.

It may be helpful to consider the case of a $1$-simplex $12$.  Here there is only one possible ordering for the boundary faces, since they have only one vertex.  However, when you take the boundary, you still take the difference $2-1$, with a minus sign on the $1$.

Comment: Well that's the thing, how could one come up with the general definition of the boundary without this thought process? What I did was consistent for $0,1,2$ simplicies but failed for $n=3$. I got lucky that for $n <2$, there was only "one" way to go.

Comment: What you did gives the wrong answer for all $n>0$, and I don't know what you mean when you claim it is "consistent".  For instance, when $n=1$, it would say the boundary is $1+2$ instead of $2-1$.  (Or else, I don't understand how you are extrapolating what you did for $n=3$ to other values of $n$.)

Comment: Hm thats odd, because I write it for say $n=2$, I get $12 + 23 + 31 = 12 + 23 - 13$. I can't see why I am having such a difference when I move to $n = 3$.

Comment: Why are you writing $31$ instead of $13$?  I'm not sure what pattern you're following...

Comment: For example, for the face $123$ on the $3-$simplex, just that one only. I would never get $-$sign, but everywhere i read they just go straight into the formula.

Comment: I write $31$ because it is the directed segment from $3 \to 1$.

Comment: But why?  Why did you choose to direct it from $3$ to $1$, instead of from $1$ to $3$?  And why on the $3$-simplex did you choose the orderings on each face that you did?  As far as I can tell you are just following your vague intuition and not any actual logic...

Comment: Or perhaps more accurately, you are following some logic, but you are using totally different logic in the case of a 2-simplex than in the case of a 3-simplex.  For the 3-simplex, you just used the "default" ordering on each face, whereas for the 2-simplex you made some geometric choice of what ordering makes sense for "going around the boundary".

Comment: Maybe I'll draw a picture. But for the $2-$simplex $123$ it goes in the direction $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 1$ (counterclockwise). I chose the ordering on the $3-$simplex $1234$ because the default positive orientation is $1\to2\to3\to4 \to 1$

Comment: Right, for the $2-$simplex, I went around the boundary, yielding $31$.

Comment: Thinking geometrically on the $3$-simplex, compare faces $123$ and $124$.  Can you see that the orientations given by the orderings $123$ and $124$ are "opposite"?  (In your picture in the question, looking from outside the simplex, 1231 is counterclockwise but 1241 is clockwise.)  So $123$ and $124$ should have opposite signs in the boundary.  It is a somewhat arbitrary choice that $123$ gets the negative sign and $124$ gets the positive sign.

Comment: I am somewhat with you now. But without using the general formula, how do I know the choice? Am I wrong to still leave those "arrows" in my picture? Because they seem to be the root of my confusion in where I am "cycling". (https://i.imgur.com/Izncj4o.png picture of $2-$simplex)

Comment: As I said, the choice of the sign in the formula is pretty much just an arbitrary convention (in fact, I have seen different books that have opposite conventions).  You might be able to make some geometric argument that one choice is more natural than the other, but you're probably best off just thinking of it as an arbitrary choice.  I don't know what you're doing with the arrows you drew, so I don't know whether it is "wrong" to draw them.

Comment: The arrows were meant to illustrate the orientation of the faces...

Comment: OK, but you're just drawing the orientations of the faces given by the ordering on their vertices.  As I said in the answer, that's not the same as the orientation they have as part of the boundary.

Comment: So without using any formula, how do we decide the orientation of the boundary face then? For $n < 3$, we just go by the ordering of the vertices.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Why do you need to decide the orientation without using the formula?  That's what the formula is for...it's a definition, not a theorem.  I also dispute your characterization of what happens for $n<3$: I don't know what you mean by "just go by the ordering of the vertices", but I don't see any coherent interpretation of this that gives the right answer for both $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: Because some of this thought process must have been done in order to define the formula of the boundary in the first place. By "go by the ordering of the vertices" I mean the orientation. For example $123$ gives me the counterclockwise orientation where as $321$ gives me clockwise.

Comment: The definition of the boundary is chosen to be what it is because it works.  It is motivated by simple geometric intuition in low dimensions ($n=1$ and $n=2$ if you like), and then extrapolated to higher dimensions by just following the algebraic pattern, which luckily turns out to work very well.

Comment: If you want to think about it geometrically in the case $n=3$, it's just the clockwise/counterclockwise business I mentioned before when comparing faces $123$ and $124$ (but you could make a good case that this is a post hoc geometric interpretation of the formula, rather than a prior motivation for the formula).

Comment: As for your claim about "going by the ordering of the vertices", I still have no idea how you are claiming that gives the right answer in the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$.  How are you choosing the order of the vertices to use?  And in the case $n=1$, how are you choosing that one of the vertices should have a minus sign in the boundary?

Comment: Okay so for $n=1$, it is just a directed segment $12$, so final point - beginning point = $2-1$

Comment: So I think this will answer the question about the definition of the boundary. How do we compute the boundary geometrically for a $3-$simplex. For example the faces $123$ and $341$ are supposed to have "opposite" orientation, but I can't see that.

Comment: But why?  Why are you subtracting instead of adding?  You never mentioned that as part of your rule for "going by the ordering of the vertices".  I really really think that there is no coherent rule you actually have in mind and you are just following your intuition.

Comment: Stop thinking that there is any one correct geometric answer.  Do you see that faces $123$ and $134$ have one orientation, while faces $234$ and $124$ have a different orientation?  If so, you have understood everything there is to understand.  We arbitrarily choose to call one of these orientations "positive" and the other "negative".

Comment: If you like, the "positive" orientation is the one where the circular arrows you're drawing go clockwise, if you are looking at the face from outside the tetrahedron.

Comment: Well for $1-$ simplices we have the basic definition (have to start somewhere) and the boundary of the $2-$ simplice is built upon that and so on was what I thought. (writing other answer)

Comment: So basically fix $123$ to be CCW, then moving to the adjacent face, we all keep CCW (view from the outside) so we can have a "uniform" orientation on each boundary face. This gets me $123 + 341$. For the hidden faces, I have $2\to4\to3$ CCW (viewed bottom outside) + $421$ CCW outside, but this is in total $123 + 341 -124 - 234$. So I think this makes more sense. I gotta think about definition though and how it will generalize for $n > 3$ (yes even though it has been defined already).